# Combination of logic statements in python (and, or)

Tags: python, tkinter, logic

I am in the process of making a rock, paper, scissors shoot game in tkinter currently, and am trying to write a function that determines who wins. 1 = rock, 2 = paper, 3 = scissors. The script is not printing anything except when comp == 2 and choice == 1.

```
def Winning():
    if (((comp == 2) and (choice == 1)) or ((comp == 3) and (choice == 2)) or
        ((comp == 1) and (choice == 3))):
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "YOU LOSE!!!")
    if (((choice == 2) and (comp == 1)) or ((choice == 3) and (comp == 2)) 
      or ((choice == 1) and (comp == 3))):
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "YOU WIN!!!")
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "DRAW!!!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where does you function get `comp` and `choice` ?

Something like this would work :

```
from tkinter import messagebox

rock=1
paper=2
scissors=3


def Winning(comp, choice):
    if (((comp == 2) and (choice == 1)) or ((comp == 3) and (choice == 2)) or((comp == 1) and (choice == 3))):
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "YOU LOSE!!!")
    if (((choice == 2) and (comp == 1)) or ((choice == 3) and (comp == 2)) or((choice == 1) and (comp == 3))):
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "YOU WIN!!!")
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "DRAW!!!")


Winning(rock, paper)
```

Is this what you want ?

Comment: You did not have any parameters to your function `def Winning():` to `def Winning(comp, choice):`

Answer (score 2):

I think you went about this the wrong way.  Assuming we have to use numeric input, I would do:

```
ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS = range(1, 4)

roshambo = {
    ROCK: SCISSORS,
    PAPER: ROCK,
    SCISSORS: PAPER
}

def Winning(comp, choice):
    if comp == choice:
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "DRAW!!!")
    elif comp == roshambo[choice]:
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "YOU WIN!!!")
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "YOU LOSE!!!")
```

This makes your logic clear and simplifies the code.  And, it makes it easier to extend the problem:

```
ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS, LIZARD, SPOCK = range(1, 6)

roshambo = {
    ROCK: [LIZARD, SCISSORS],
    PAPER: [ROCK, SPOCK],
    SCISSORS: [PAPER, LIZARD],
    LIZARD: [SPOCK, PAPER],
    SPOCK: [SCISSORS, ROCK]
}

def Winning(comp, choice):
    if comp == choice:
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "DRAW!!!")
    elif comp in roshambo[choice]:
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "YOU WIN!!!")
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "YOU LOSE!!!")
```

Dictionaries are your friend, never program without them!